# Ошибка при вызове класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим есть некий файл Main.py

```
#                   ИМПОРТЫ
import requests
#                   КОД
class vkmix_pyapi:
    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.api_key = api_key
    def getBalance(self):
        a=requests.get('https://vkmix.com/api/2/getBalance', params={'api_token':self.api_key})
        return a.json()
    def getTasks(self, offset , count, ids=None):
        if ids == None:
            vas = requests.get('https://vkmix.com/api/2/getTasks', params = {'api_token':self.api_key, 'count':count, 'offset':offset}) 
        else:
            vas = requests.get('https://vkmix.com/api/2/getTasks', params = {'api_token':self.api_key, 'count':count, 'offset':offset, 'ids':ids})
        return vas.json()
```

И есть другой файл допустим sai.py

```
import Main
p = vkmix_pyapi('Тут должен быть токен но я его убрал')
print(p.getBalance())
```

В итоге при запуске файла sai выходит

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\Documents\Python_apps\vkmix_pyapi\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    p = vkmix_pyapi('Тут должен быть токен но я его убрал')
NameError: name 'vkmix_pyapi' is not defined
```

**Как с этим бороться?**

Comment: Так знаете в чём прикол если я импортирую через from Main import * то всё норм

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы импортируете Main так – `import Main`, то к любому атрибуту это модуля нужно обращаться так – `Main.vkmix_pyapi`. Вы можете импортировать определенный атрибут так – `from Main import vkmix_pyapi` или импортировать сразу все – `from Main import *` (**лучше так не делать, потому что имена импортированных атрибутов могут буть такие же как имена атрибутов в том модуле куда вы импортируете**), тогда вы сможете обращаться к атрибуту напрямую.

https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/rabota-s-modulyami-sozdanie-podklyuchenie-instrukciyami-import-i-from.html